# Detecting SPA UI page change for chrome extension

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that is configured to run at

http://my.url/ui/foo

The /ui namespace is used by a section of the site that is managed by AngularJS. As such, transitioning between routes within /ui is managed client-side.

When the page at /ui/foo is first loaded, the chrome extension fires appropriately. However, if I transition in the client side from /ui/foo to /ui/bar and then back to /ui/foo, the chrome extension inject script is not re-firing. I assume it is something to do with the lack of document_start, document_end and document_idle hooks when transitioning locally between angular routes.

What is the best/appropriate/correct way for me to get my chrome extension to detect a local route change and re-fire, the same as it would if I went from /ui/foo to /something-not-client-managed to /ui/foo again?

Comment: See [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)

Comment: Spot on thanks I think you've given me what I need. Funnily enough I'm using the event listener message/window method already for part of it, I just assumed there would be a more formal way. Fortunately I have access to the underlying UI code so I'll just have it send an event to the DOM every time the route changes. Thanks again!

Comment: I have the same problem. Would love to hear more about this.